# New to javascript arrays, need some help

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an assignment in which I need to make two arrays (NAME and SALES). I need to populate the array of up to 100 components. Then, I need to calculate gross pay using a calcPay() function.  I am having trouble figuring out how to get the function to work, it either prints the resulting table with the Pay column as 'undeclared', or it just stops working when it comes to that spot, no matter how many NAMES and SALES are entered into the array.  I have this in the body script:

```
var i=0;
var NAME = new Array();
var SALES = new Array();
do
{
   NAME[i]=getName();
   SALES[i]=getSales();
   i++;
   var again=confirm("Would you like to enter another salesperson's stats?");
}while(again && i<=100);

var i=0;
for (var i=0;i<NAME.length;i++)
{
   printRow();
}
```

And this is the header:

```
function getName()
{
   do
     {
        var name=prompt("What is the salesperson's full name?");
     }while (name==""||name==null);
   return name;
}

function getSales()
{
   do
     {
        var sales=prompt("Please enter salesperson's sales.");
     }while(sales==""||isNaN(sales));
   return parseFloat(sales);
}

calcPay(sales)
{
   var pay=sales*.1+1000;
   return pay;
}

function printRow()
{
    document.write("<tr>");
    document.write("<td>"+NAME[i]+"</td>");
    document.write("<td>"+SALES[i]+"</td>");
    var payment=calcPay(SALES[i]);
    document.write("<td>"+payment+"</td>");
    document.write("</tr>");
}
```

This is not the full extent of the assignment by any means, I just want to make sure that I have a handle on the feeding and manipulating of the arrays (which I don't, obviously).
Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Have a look at the console which error you get. And don't use `document.write`.

Comment: `calcPay(sales)` should be `function calcPay(sales)`

Comment: Oh my God.  It is absolutely amazing how you can miss the simplest things.  Thank you.

Comment: Also, we have to use document.write, it is in our instructions.  We are not starting DOM methods until later in the week.

Comment: I suggest that you use `var NAME = [];` instead of `var NAME = new Array();`.

Comment: @unit if you _must_ use `document.write` then please use [`document.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.open) and [`document.close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.close). Open your document properly for writing and close it properly rather then using it in a hackish/amateur fashion. Don't forget to `document.write("<html><body><table><tbody>")` and `document.write("</tbody></table></body></html>")`

Comment: @Raynos   Too funny that you would call it 'hackish/amateur', it's the only way we've been taught thus far!  We haven't even been told you need to open and close document.  That makes me laugh.  Thanks!

Comment: @unit In general using `document.write` is almost always wrong. You should not be writing HTML to the document using javascript. You should be writing it using HTML text in a html file and manipulating the DOM loaded from HTML using DOM manipulation API. I'm afraid web development courses have a habit of teaching you bad practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally - your code works, find it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/osher/GhZSf/

However - 
there is a missing "function" before calcPay

```
calcPay(sales)
{
   var pay=sales*.1+1000;
   return pay;
}
```

should be

```
function calcPay(sales)
{
   var pay=sales*.1+1000;
   return pay;
}
```

that's all

Comment: Thank you all, appreciate it.  Feeling a little bit dumb, but sometimes it's nice when it's something small (at least that's what I tell my wife).

Answer (score -3):

name and sales are out of scope this function will not do what you think it will and even if it does it is wrong.
Use an if statement .

```
function getName()
{
   do
     {
        var name=prompt("What is the salesperson's full name?");
     }while (name==""||name==null);
   return name;
}

function getSales()
{
   do
     {
        var sales=prompt("Please enter salesperson's sales.");
     }while(sales==""||isNaN(sales));
   return parseFloat(sales);
}
```

Comment: That's wrong. In JavaScript variable scope is not their block but the function they are declared in.

Comment: And as for scope I was not refering to function scope I was refering to the loop scope. He is declaring the var inside the do statement

Comment: @The_asMan - that's exactly what I was talking about.
In JavaScript - it does not matter where you declare the variable, as long as 1) it is declared before it is used 2) it is used ither in the same function (not block) that it is declared in, - OR - in a function that is declared **next-to** it. Read about closure :)
Also - when re-declaring a var - the `var` is ignored the second time it is met, however - assignments are executed nonetheless.

Comment: This is not a case about closures so don't even bring that up you will just confuse unit more. What you fail to understand is this is college level homework and those functions are wrong period. If you studied how functions are create whats the first thing you do? DEClARE VARS. What he is doing here is a very bad practice working or not, it is wrong

Comment: @The_asMan If he was asking about best practices of declaring functions - I would have consider code-organization rants. However - talking about confusing unit - with all the good will, I rather answer to his question then ranting about things he did not ask :).
And for you - do you know why variables are declared on the beginning of the function? would you still be so anal if your function is 3 lines that declare 1 var?

Comment: You seriously are going to down vote me brown? Long after he probably got an F on his assignment because you are giving bad advice?